# How to send a SOAP request with an authentication header in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I have created a request using SoapClient towards a wsdl. I have managed to get through and get a list of functions using `__getFunctions()`, so I can confirm my URL is working.

The issue lies when calling a function, I receive a `Could not connect to host` error message. I should also mention I use Laravel and the error message does not give me any more information.

I personally believe it is an authentication based issue, as I need to parse a username and password through the header and I might have gotten some syntax wrong.

My PHP function:

```
try {
            $wsdlUrl = 'https://myurl.com/Service.svc?wsdl';
            $context = [
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            ];
            $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array('stream_context' => $context));

            $authentication = array(
                'Username' => env('USERNAME'),
                'Password' => env('PASSWORD')
            );

            //Soap Header
            $header = new SoapHeader(
                'https://myurl.com/',
                'Credentials',
                $authentication,
                false
            );
            $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);


            return $client->GetElement(['ID' => '462493']);


        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::error($e->getMessage());
    }
```

and the xml I'm trying to match:

```
  <soapenv:Header>
    <Credentials>
      <Password>Password</Password>
      <Username>Brugernavn</Username>
    </Credentials>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <GetElementRequestType>
      <ID>4624393</ID>
    </GetElementRequestType>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few elementary things wrong in your code. Let us go through the different things you have to do right, when dealing with soap requests and responses with PHP.

### Try/catch blocks with soap

When dealing with soap, there 's always thrown a `SoapFault`. The `SoapFault` class inherits directly from `Exception`. With this in mind you have to catch a `SoapFault` and not an `ErrorException`.

```
try {
    // doing some soap stuff here
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    Log::error($fault->getMessage());
}
```

Optionally you can catch different exceptions with different catch blocks if you are awaiting some other throwable stuff.

```
try {

} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    // catches soap faults
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    // catches error exceptions
} finally {
    // final catch of everything else
}
```

The `finally` statement will always be executed no matter what kind of throwable was thrown before.

### The client options

As long as you 're not dealing with any certificates you do not have to create an context. You can, but it would work without that context. In your case, as you 're just dealing with username and password credentials, the context is just another possible source of error.
For development the options of the `SoapClient` class should look as follows.

```
try {
    $wsdl = 'https://www.domain.tld/service?wsdl';
    $options = [
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'trace' => true,
    ];

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    if ($client) {
        // get the last sent request
        var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());

        // get the last response
        var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
    }

    var_dump($fault);
}
```

With the `trace` option you enable the functions for getting the last request and response. This can be quite helpful during development. The `exception` option forces the client to throw exceptions in any case. If this is no set the client can be calm in an error case.

### Data models with soap

Just assume that the PHP Soap extension is strictly object oriented. So you have to deal with value objects and elements, that are directly described in the wsdl file. You can view the definitions mostly by calling the wsdl url directy in the broser. All complex and simple types and function calls are described there.

So when we look at your soap header, we see  credentials object (complex type) with the properties username and password. We can directy use that in php as a class.

```
class Credentials
{
    protected string $Password;
    protected string $Username;

    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->Password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->Password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->Username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->Username = $username;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see this is a simple data model of the credentials. You now have to initialize it and force it as a soap header.

```
$credentials = (new Credentials())
    ->setPassword('bla')
    ->setUsername('blubb');

$header = new SoapHeader(
    'http://www.domain.tld/namespace',
    'Credentials',
    new SoapVar($credentials, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, '', '', 'Credentials', '')
);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$response = $client->GetElement([ 'ID' => 1234 ]);
```

If this is not working, remember the trace function. In case of a soap fault try to have a look at the last sent request. In most cases you can see, that there 's something wrong with the request xml structure.

Comment: Removed my last comment as I got the var_dumping working - will test with the requests/responses and return.

Comment: After messing around for the last couple of hours, I have managed to create a valid XML request, in the sense if I copy the generated XML text into Insomnia/Postman, it goes right through. However, if I do it through my Laravel project using PHP, I still get 'Could not connect to host'. If I write an invalid function, I get an 'Function X is not a valid method for this service, so it definitely recognizes my call.

Comment: This means, that the client creates a valid xml request, right? Can you show me the xml the client creates? The problem could be the wsdl address itself. Since the PHP SoapClient class is pretty strict with namespaces and xsd definitions, it could be, that a reference to a W3C hostet definition is not working because of a delay the W3C has put on definitions. In that case you have to edit the wsdl file and host it locally on your own server.

Comment: I found the issue, it was a combination of me misunderstanding concepts you explained above, and the final thing to solve for me was adding the 'location' as an option. I did not think this was needed, as the documentation states,  but after adding my wsdl link, just without the ?wsdl part to location option, it went straight through. I will however accept your answer, as it helped me a ton the last few hours!